# Using/installing AngularJS smart-table without nodejs

Tags: angularjs, smart-table

I want to use Angular smart-table in my html code.

My environment:

server-side -  Apache vs java

client side - html with angular

I downloaded the smart-table repository but I have difficulty to install the module manually and there is no instructions or tutorial for this on the web

What i tried so far is:

1. In my html file i am pointing to smart-table.js and smart-table.min.js

   ```
   <script src="../app/assets/js/smart-table.js"></script>
   <script src="../app/assets/js/smart-table.min.js"></script>
   ```

2.in my app I am referencing 'smart-table':

```
var app = angular.module('FarmManagment', ['smart-table']);
```

but it's not working the smart-table futures are not recognized.

please help to configure this correctly!!!

this is my code in general:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>get farms angularjs tester</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/normalize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../app/assets/css/search box">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../js/bootstrap.min.css">



    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

    <script src="../app/assets/js/smart-table.js"></script>
    <script src="../app/assets/js/smart-table.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body ng-app="FarmManagment" ng-controller="mainCtrl">






    <!-- Data table -->
    <table id="auditTable" class="table table-hover" st-table="displayedCollection" st-safe-src="rowCollection" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th st-sort="FarmName">Farm Name</th>
                ...
                ...
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id ="tbody">
            <tr ng-repeat="row in rowCollection">
                <td ng-bind="row.FarmName"></td>
                ...
                ...
            </tr>

        </tbody>
    </table>

    <script>
        var app = angular.module('FarmManagment', ['smart-table']);
        app.controller('mainCtrl', function ($scope,$http) {
            $http.get('<path>').then(function(response) {
                $scope.rowCollection = response.data.farms;
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
```

Thanks
Dima

Comment: you never define `$scope.displayedCollection`. Any errors thrown in browser console?

Comment: Also you only need one version of smart-table.js. not both

Comment: Hi , there is no errors regarding  $scope.displayedCollection and i tried without it still same problem the library just not recognized. Also tried both imports one by one separately but still not recognized